# C++ keyboard even with SendInput - creating an autologin

Tags: c++, char

as said in title I am creating an app to auto login, with account and password it grabs from a filestream.

I have a function, DirectInput which takes a 'char' as parameter, and sends it as input from keyboard.The problem is I can not cast the parameter as int i, because it is not surrounded by ''.

How would I be able to work this out?

```
#include <regex>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>

using namespace std;

void DirectInput(char _key) {
     INPUT key;
     memset(&key, 0, sizeof(INPUT));
     key.type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
     key.ki.dwExtraInfo = GetMessageExtraInfo();
     key.ki.wScan = static_cast<WORD>(MapVirtualKeyEx(VkKeyScanA(_key), MAPVK_VK_TO_VSC, GetKeyboardLayout(0)));
     key.ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_SCANCODE;

     SendInput(1, &key, sizeof(INPUT));

     key.ki.dwExtraInfo = GetMessageExtraInfo();
     key.ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_SCANCODE | KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;

     SendInput(1, &key, sizeof(INPUT));
}

string PrintMatch(std::string str, std::regex reg) {                                                // Iterate through the outputted CMD to define "port" and "auth token".
       smatch matches;
       while (regex_search(str, matches, reg)) { //while????
          cout << matches.str(1) << endl;
          break;
       }

       return matches.str(1);

}

int main() {
    cout << "AutoLogger testing phase! " << endl;

    string text;    
    string file_name = "freshaccounts.txt";
    ifstream fresh_accounts(file_name);
    vector<string> fresh_accounts_data;
    string current_line;

    if (!fresh_accounts)
        cout << "Can't open freshaccounts.txt make sure it's there!" << endl;
    
    getline(fresh_accounts, current_line);

    cout << "1st line acc is:" << endl;
    cout << current_line << endl;

    regex user("EUW:(\\w+)");
    string username = PrintMatch(current_line, user);    
    regex reg_pass(username + ":(\\w+)");
    string password = PrintMatch(current_line, reg_pass);
    int user_length = username.length();
    int pass_length = password.length();
    vector<int> user_vect;

    user_vect.push_back(user_length);

    HWND hwndLeague = FindWindowA(0, ("Riot Client"));

    SetForegroundWindow(hwndLeague);

    Sleep(150);

    for (int i = 0; i < user_length; i++) {
        cout << username.at(i);
        DirectInput(i);      // <---------- THIS IS THE PROBLEM! i is not surrounded by ''
        Sleep(1000);
    }
}
```

Thank you in advandce!
Regards!

Fixed it, a bit sleepy, however!:

```
for (int i = 0; i < user_length; i++) {
     cout << username.at(i) << endl;
     char input = username.at(i);
     DirectInput(input);
     Sleep(500);
}
```

It doesn't output the 1st letter in the string with DirectInput, it outputs it through the  cout << username.at(i) << endl;??

Comment: I found out the reason it doesn't  input the character at index 0, is because it is capital - it doesn't input any capital characters at all. How would I be able to make my SendInput function handle capital characters? :3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For upper-case:

```
void DirectInput(char _key)
{
    HKL kbl = GetKeyboardLayout(0);
    INPUT ip;
    ip.type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
    ip.ki.time = 0;
    ip.ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_UNICODE;
    if ((int)mK < 65 && (int)mK>90) //for lowercase
    {
        ip.ki.wScan = 0;
        ip.ki.wVk = VkKeyScanEx(mK, kbl);
    }
    else //for uppercase
    {
        ip.ki.wScan = mK;
        ip.ki.wVk = 0;

    }
    ip.ki.dwExtraInfo = 0;
    SendInput(1, &ip, sizeof(INPUT));
}
```